# common left and right coset representatives for a subgroup of finite index

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $G$ is a group, and that $H$ is a (not necessarily normal) subgroup of $G$ having finite index $r=[G:H]$. A subset $\{x_1,\cdots,x_r\}\subset{G}$ is called a *left* *transversal* of $H$ in $G$ provided that $\{x_1{H},\cdots,x_r{H}\}$ is complete set of $r$ distinct left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Similarly, a subset $\{y_1,\cdots,y_r\}\subset{G}$ is called a *right* *transversal* of $H$ in $G$ provided that $\{{H}y_1,\cdots,{H}y_r\}$ is a complete set of $r$ distinct right cosets of $H$ in $G$.  Prove that there exists a distinguished subset $\{x_1,\cdots,x_r\}\subset{G}$ that is *simultaneously* (both) a left and a right transversal of $H$ in $G$; i.e. such that $$G={\bigcup}^{r}_{j=1}{x_j}H = {\bigcup}^{r}_{j=1} H{x_j}.$$
Not sure how to approach this. I felt that that the conjugates of $H$ might play a role, and proved that any subgroup of the form $gHg^{-1}$ must also have index $r$. But am not able to use this fact! This problem seems to have been discussed on math stack exchange but I cannot find a solution. As respondents observed, this is a consequence of Hall's "marriage theorem". Is there a direct proof of this fact which does not use the marriage theorem?

Comment: By definition we have $r$ cosets, so that $G$ is a union of these cosets. You don't have to do much. Did you cover the standard properties of cosets?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's a standard application of Hall's theorem (the so-called marriage theorem) but I wouldn't say it's exactly trivial.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/178458

Comment: @DietrichBurde Did you read the question carefully? It is not assumed that $H$ is a *normal* subgroup.

Comment: Do you know how to prove it if $G$ is a finite group? The case of a finite index subgroup of an infinite group can be reduced to the case of a finite group. By the way, it's also true that a common transversal exists if $H$ is a finite subgroup of infinite index, But there are counterexamples when $H$ is an infinite subgroup of infinite index.

Comment: Folks! Just saw your responses. The problem does not assume that $G$ is a finite group, or that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Of course, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, the result is immediate, since $gH=Hg$ for every $g\in{G}$.

Comment: I edited the question and posed it (hopefully) with greater clarity after the (useful) comments responding to my question.