# Does there always exist a double transversal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Suppose $G$ is a group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. Let's call $T \subset G$ a left/right transversal of $H$ iff it is a system of representatives of left/right cosets of $H$ respectively. Let's call $T$ a double transversal of $H$ iff it is both left and right transversal of $H$ simultaneously. Does a double transversal exist for every subgroup $H$ of $G$?

In case when $H$ is finite, a double transversal for $H$ can be built the following way:

Suppose $g \in G$ is an arbitrary element. Then the double coset $HgH$ can be represented as union of the right and left cosets from the collections $R = \{Hgh' | h' \in H\}$ and $L = \{hgH | h \in H\}$ respectively. Note, that because $\bigcup R = HgH = \bigcup L$, we have $|L| = \frac{|HgH|}{|H|} = |R| = t$. Suppose, $R = \{Hgh_i'\}_{i=1}^t$ and $L = \{h_igH\}_{i=1}^t$ Then $h_igh_i' \in Hgh_i \cap h_igH$. That means, that $\{h_igh_i'\}_{i=1}^t$ is both a system of representatives from $R$ and a system of representatoives from $L$.

Since double cosets partition $G$, we can repeat the process for all double cosets to form the double transversal we were trying to build.

That case is easily generalised to the one when $H$ contains a finite index subgroup $N$, which is normal in $G$, by applying the previous result to quotients. However, I have no idea what to do in case when $H$ has no such subgroup.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178186/relation-between-left-and-right-coset-representatives-of-a-subgroup/178458#178458) answer the question? See especially the non-accepted answer.  [This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3521859/common-left-and-right-coset-representatives-for-a-subgroup-of-finite-index) which does not have posted answers, suggests in comments that it can be solved with an application of Hall's Marriage Theorem.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, the question you linked is indeed related to my question. However, it deals only with finite-index subgroups, which are a special case of the condition from the last paragraph of my question (due to the fact that any finite-index subgroup of $G$ contains a finite index normal subgroup of $G$). I am, however, asking, whether the same holds for **all** subgroups (including infinite-index ones).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, the proof of this fact for finite-index subgroups using Hall's Marriage Theorem is indeed a very neat one, but I doubt that it can be generalised to my case (because Hall's Marriage Theorem does not hold in general for infinite sets, as demonstrated by Marshall Hall Jr. in "Combinatorial Theory")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$ of the Baumslag-Solitar group $${\rm BS}(1,2) = \langle a,b \mid b^{-1}ab = a^2 \rangle$$
is a counterexample.

In this group, the left coset $bH$ is the disjoint union of two right cosets $Hb \cup Hba$, with elements $ba^{2k}$ in $Hb$ and elements $ba^{2k+1}$ in $Hba$.

But a common left and right transversal would have to contain elements from $Hb$ and $Hba$ and so it would contain two elements from $bH$.